# Azure DocumentDB and Spring Boot conflict

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

In my spring boot application I run this simple code `client.getDatabaseAccount()` in two places:

**1) In `main` method. Before spring boot is "booted", `DocumentClient` works great!!!**

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
// just to test if it can connect to cosmos db before spring boot starts 
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient("URL","KEY", new ConnectionPolicy(), ConsistencyLevel.Session); 
// this runs great and connects to azure cosmos db. 
client.getDatabaseAccount();
SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}
```

**2) In a Service class. When the below method (with the exact same code `client.getDatabaseAccount()`) is called, it throws an exception**

```
@Service 
@Component 
public class TestService { 
public DocumentClient connectCosmos() throws Exception { 
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient("URL","KEY", new ConnectionPolicy(), ConsistencyLevel.Session); 
// this throws an exception 
client.getDatabaseAccount(); 
}
}
```

---

ERROR:

```
Execution encountered exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target, status code 403 sub status code null.
```

**Clearly there is no problem with certificate since the two exact pieces of code run within the same SpringBootApplication**

---

Here is the POM  `azure-documentdb`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-documentdb</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Why does this happen? **My only guess is Spring Boot doesn't like azure-documentdb.** How to execute `azure-documentdb` code within Spring Boot. I DON'T WANT TO USE `Azure Document DB Spring Boot Starter` because my spring boot backend database is something else, and I only need  `azure-documentdb`  to retreive little data. I don't want `Azure Document DB Spring Boot Starter` to backup the whole Spring Boot project as  `ORM`. So is it possible to have `azure-documentdb` pom inside of a spring boot project?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a github project ? Also it will help to know your application yml configuration and how you run the application ( if any jvm args are provided). The error you see is thrown by HttpClient used by DocumentClient, It could be that your trust store setting is overridden by spring boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John I did something very similar to what you tried and it worked for me without any issue.

```java
    @Service  
    public class CosmosService {
        public  void connectCosmos() throws Exception {
            DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient("https://somename-cosmosdb.documents.azure.com:443/", "somepassword", new ConnectionPolicy(), ConsistencyLevel.Session);
            client.getDatabaseAccount();

            FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions();
            options.setEnableCrossPartitionQuery(true);
            List<Document> result = client
                    .queryDocuments(
                            "dbs/" + "samples" + "/colls/" + "orders",
                            "SELECT * FROM c",
                            options)
                    .getQueryIterable()
                    .toList();
            result.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        }
}
```

Application class

```java
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class RatellaStackApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

        @Autowired
        CosmosService cosmosService;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(RatellaStackApplication.class, args);
        }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        cosmosService.connectCosmos();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    }
```

Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-documentdb</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

calling the service method from the controller works too.

```java
    @RestController
    public class MyController {
        @Autowired
        CosmosService cosmosService;

        @GetMapping("/hello")
        public String hello() throws Exception {
            cosmosService.connectCosmos();
            return "OK";
        }
    }
```

Link to the source code of the Rest API. For simplicity I put everything in the SpringBoot Application class. 
https://gist.github.com/RaviTella/e544ef7b266ba425abead7f05193f717

Comment: Thank you. Yes this runs for me too if it's a `CommandLineRunner`. I'm trying to call it from a fully fledged Spring Boot web app Controller. Could you please call `cosmosService.connectCosmos();` from a different `Controller`, not within the `main` class, not within the `CommandLineRunner`. Please call `cosmosService.connectCosmos();` from some regular class. Let's say you have one button in your Spring Boot application. A user clicks that button, and the connection happens. Is this possible?

Comment: John, That works too. I have updated my post with the code.

Comment: I get it. But my point is I'm tryint Spring Boot. NOt command line . Spring Boot works on a port 8080 or 443 . I think this is what causing the issue. command line runner will of course work

Comment: Instead of `implements CommandLineRunner` can you make it a spring boot web app? this doesnt work for me

Comment: John. I built a spring boot Rest API.  MyController is in a new spring boot application. There is no CommandLineRunner involved.

Comment: I have updated the post with the link to the code for the Spring boot rest API.

Answer (score 1):

How about getting the `documentClient` from `applicationContext` instead of initializing a new one. Let spring initialize one for you.

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

DocumentClient documentClient = (DocumentClient) applicationContext.getBean(DocumentClient.class);
```

What version of Spring Boot are you using ?
Are you using spring-data-cosmosdb SDK ?

Comment: Thank you. But I can't have it initialized this way (there are good reasons for this). It must be hard coded. Anyway, why would it work in the main method and not work elsewhere? That's astonishing

Comment: I hardcoded those two test lines on purpose to make sure there are no `run time problems`. Those two lines: `DocumentClient client = new .....` and `client.getDatabaseAccount()` work in `main`. So they should also work in any other parts. It's like imagine if `System.out.println` works in `main` but not elsewhere....that would be odd